# Find the position of the last english character in a stream

Tags: java, character-encoding, inputstream

I have a reader which receives message packets as stream(ByteArrayInputStream).
Each packet contains data consisting of English characters followed by binary digits.

```
adghfjiyromn1000101010100......
```

What is the most efficient way to copy over(not strip) the characters out of this stream as a sequence.
So,expected output of the above packet would be(without modifying the original stream) :

```
adghfjiyromn
```

I am not only concerned about the logic,but also the exact stream manipulation routines to use;considering that the reader would read about 3-4 packets every second hypothetically.
It would also help to provide the justification on why we would prefer a particular data type(byte[],char[] or string) for tackling this.

Comment: Please give an input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to read the ByteArrayInputStream byte by byte:

```
ByteArrayInputStream msg = ...
int c;
String s;
while ((c = msg.read())!= -1) {
  char x = (char) c;
  if (x=='1' || x=='0') break;
  s += x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think its the best way :

1-convert Your ByteArrayInputStream to String ( or StringBuffer)
2-find first Index of 0 or 1
3-use substring ( 0 , FIRST_INDEX )

Answer (score 0):

You : Each packet contains data consisting of English characters followed by binary digits.
Me : Data is in bytearrayinputstream, hence everything is in binary.
Does your 1000101010100...... are characters '1' & '0'?

If yes

```
ByteArrayInputStream msg =  //whatever
        int totalBytes = msg.available();
        int c;
        while ((c = msg.read())!= -1) {
          char x = (char) c;
          if (x=='1' || x=='0') break;
        }
        int currentPos = msg.available() + 1; //you need to unread the 1st 0 or 1
        System.out.println("Position = "+(totalBytes-currentPos));
```